# invalid syntax when trying to open jupyter notebook

Tags: python

when i type in the command jupyter notebook in my terminal,i am getting this error.
it was working fine and suddenly this seems to pop up

```
decentmakeover@DecentMakeover:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, 
in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 74, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 16, in < 
module>
    from jupyter_client.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manager import KernelManager, run_kernel
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .session import Session
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 61, in <module>
   from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, 
date_default
  File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/jupyter_client/jsonutil.py", line 11, in <module>
   from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
 File "/home/decentmakeover/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packa 
ges/dateutil/parser.py", line 303
    raise ValueError, "unknown string format"
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Try `ipython kernel install`. then `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: i get the same but lengthier error this time,want me to post the error?

Comment: update your machine, then apply..

Comment: same errror sir,

Comment: If now it's "lengthier error", update question. "I was working fine..." - do you remember, what have you changed?

Comment: i have a different path for anaconda and for ubuntu python ,i was swtiching between them ,the jupyter was installed in anaconda

Comment: Try to install jupyter in a venv: goal of venvs is to create a separated environment for packages to avoid conflicts between projects, and you're probably just facing a package conflict.